find an element by Xpath using selenium Java
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;

public class SeleniumBasics {
    
public static void main(String[] args) {  
        
        WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();  
        driver.get("https://formy-project.herokuapp.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/div[1]/div[1]/li[1]")).click();
        
    }  

}


Im trying to click on the element "autocomplete" in this page https://formy-project.herokuapp.com/...not working ..any help pleae?
Absolute Xpath
relative Xpath
find by element

//body/div[1]/div[1]/li[1]

You are locating the <li> element. You should be locating the <a> element.
Also don't use absolute XPath. Use relative XPath as below.
//a[@class='btn btn-lg' and text()='Autocomplete']


you can use text() function to find element instead of using absolute xpath. //a[text()='Autocomplete']

didn't work, I got an error.
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='autocomplete']")).click();

you should capitalize the "A" => "Autocomplete" like this. Because text() function will get the text between 2 tags 

Yes, I tried it first, didn't work either.

What's the error? Does it show element cannot be located?

Unable to find CDP implementation matching 126
juin 27, 2024 11:14:10 A.M. org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver lambda$new$5
Unable to find version of CDP to use for 126.0.6478.1 You may need to include a dependency on a specific version of the CDP using something similar to org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v86:4.16. where the version ("v86") matches the version of the chromium-based browser you're using and the version number of the artifact is the same as Selenium's.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

I saw there were 2 text contains "Autocomplete" => so change the above xpath to //div[@class='jumbotron-fluid']//a[text()='Autocomplete']

another way you can try is javascript executor:
WebElement autocompleteElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='jumbotron-fluid']//a[text()='Autocomplete']")); JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;         js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", autocompleteElement);
